# Wordpress duplicator doesn't work on my website

Tags: php, wordpress

I worked on a website on my local server and then I used the plugin Duplicator to create a installer for my website. I installed that on my website, the homepage works perfectly, but when I click on other links or even the admin page, it shows me a blank page with the corect url. What can I do?

Comment: Did  you point database details properly in wp-config.php?

Comment: Start with enabling debug mode and updating your post with occured errors. 

https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Comment: When I go to other pages now it display this: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/spatiulm1/public_html/roho.com.ro/wp-content/themes/customtheme/functions.php:81) in /home/spatiulm1/public_html/roho.com.ro/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1228

Comment: The database is well connected, otherwise it wouldn't show anything.

Comment: @DanielLeoba could you post here the function around 81 line in your functions.php file ?

Comment: // Add Widget area

// wpt_create_widget ('Page Sidebar', 'page', 'Displays on the side of pages with a sidebar');

Comment: Oh... I deleted those lines, and after that it says that I have some problem in line 150... but in line 150 was only 3 blank lines after the code end, after I deleted those the website works perfectly. Thank you for help!!!